# Logging in admin UI does not entries after changing settings

Tags: solr

I am trying to debug a datimport and changed inside solr 7.7.1 admin UI the loglevel of dataimport from ERROR to ALL. This does not have any effect, furthermore the setting will go back to the original settings after restarting and reindexing.

How can I enable logging for dataimport INFO?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any changes made in [the web UI for logging](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/configuring-logging.html) are *temporary changes* and can't be persisted:

> You can control the amount of logging output in Solr by using the Admin Web interface. Select the LOGGING link. Note that this page only lets you change settings in the running system and is not saved for the next run.

The easiest way to change the logging level might be to change it when starting Solr, either through the SOLR_LOG_LEVEL environment variable, or through the `-v` parameter to `bin/solr`:

```
bin/solr start -f -v
```

This will start Solr with the DEBUG log level by default.

More detailed, permanent logging configuration is [done through the standard Log4j2 syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/configuring-logging.html#permanent-logging-settings), which can be configured in `server/resources/log4j2.xml`.